# I can't rotate bones in pose mode when trying to make a keyframe

Tags: transforms, keyframes, pose-mode

I've been watching single sapling games' tutorial series on how to make a low poly character, but when I tried to add some keyframes to the idle animation as shown in this video: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wKgH4FxKlU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZlx.png) the bones wouldn't rotate and kept snapping back to their original position.

[image: original position]

[image: attempting to rotate]

*also if I delete all my keyframes I am able to rotate again

Comment: Could you post a more precise description or even a screen capture of your blender window and the actions that you performed. There's a ton of things that could result in such a problem and we can't simply guess what every parameter on your screen look like

Comment: Sorry if my question seemed vague, I've added a few pics on exactly what actions I'm performing but there's not much else I can do to describe my problem

Comment: Yes, there is more you can describe. Did you: *right mouse click select the pose bone, pressed R, moved the mouse, see the bone rotate, pressed **left** mouse click to confirm the action, pressed **I** to insert a keyframe before proceding to another frame in the timeline*? When this the snapping occur?

Comment: So, I remapped my select button to my left click, when I rotate I'm pressing "r" and then "x", and the snapping occurs the instant I confirm the rotation. I also added a keyframe at the beginning and end of my animation similar to what is seen in the first pic